# Not printing Images to paper from Print preview from report Viewer using crystal reports

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2010

I am using SAP crystal reports for Visual studio 2010 in my application. In one of my report I have used images. I am getting image including data in my print preview in report viewer. And also I am able to take prints with data and Images in my environment. But in client place they are telling for some prints the image portion is not getting printed. I am unable to get the exact reason from my searches in internet. So If anybody has faced similar issue please be kind to help me out of this.

The picture is of IOEobject and is placed in designer by selecting the file in design time.

Is it because of the any of the reasons given below

- I have scaled the actual Image to X : 44% & Y : 44%.
- Due to the image format.
- Or due to the printer configuration in the clients' environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by assuming the problem is the picture they are printing.

The answer to your problem is likely proper troubleshooting:
Can they replicate the issue with 100% accuracy (meaning, is it refusing to print a specific image)?
If so, get the image and verify that it is supported. A quick Google shows gifs are not supported.
Try to print the same image yourself and see if it works?
Verify printer drivers etc.